# Building a library with an executable that uses it

Tags: windows, cmake, mingw-w64

I have a library "lib" and an executable "demo".

The issue I'm having is that "demo" can't get `lib_INCLUDES` and `lib_LIBS lib` variables, set by "lib". I want them set because in `demo.h` I do `#include <lib.h>` and it fails to find the include. I want CMake to make `lib.h` a global include, i.e. pass `-I /path/to/the/dir/with/lib.h/` to the compiler.

---

Source tree:

```
- src/
  - CMakeLists.txt
  - lib/
    - CMakeLists.txt
    - lib.cpp
    - lib.h
  - demo/
    - CMakeLists.txt
    - demo.cpp
    - demo.h
```

---

src/CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(test)

add_subdirectory(lib)
add_subdirectory(demo)
```

---

src/lib/CMakeLists.txt

```
add_library(lib SHARED lib.h lib.cpp)
target_include_directories(lib ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})

# defined for later use in src/demo/CMakeLists.txt
set(lib_INCLUDES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
set(lib_LIBS lib)
```

---

src/demo/CMakeLists.txt

```
include_directories(${lib_INCLUDES})
add_executable(demo demo.h demo.cpp)
target_link_libraries(demo ${lib_LIBS})

# empty! why?
message(STATUS ${lib_INCLUDES})
```

---

Tell me how "demo" can access `lib_INCLUDES` and `lib_LIBS` libraries set by "lib", they seem to be empty in `src/demo/CMakeLists.txt`.

I don't want `src/demo/CMakeLists.txt` contain paths to "lib", only `src/lib/CMakeLists.txt` should know details of "lib" and it should define nice variables for use in `src/demo/CMakeLists.txt` that hide all those details.

Please include a working CMakeLists.txt in your answer, if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read carefully documentation of [SET](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command:set) command. Your variable `lib_INCLUDES` has local scope to lib\CMakeLists.txt, so for example you can CACHE it.

Better way is to populate `INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` of `lib` by

```
target_include_directories(lib INTERFACE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
```

so the `target_link_libraries` automatically appends lib's include directories.